# Why is my redux action firing twice and how can i fix that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am a complete beginner to redux and I am trying to create a discord clone. I am trying to create login functionality using google authentication with firebase and using redux to save the state. However, whenever I login or logout, the action is fired twice and I'm not exactly sure why. This is what shows up in react dev tools:

[redux devtools trace 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XvHS.png)

[redux devtools trace 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E9bA.png)

This is my store.js code

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userReducer from '../components/Reducers/userSlice';
import appReducer from '../components/Reducers/appSlice';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({trace: true});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
    app: appReducer,
  },
});
```

this is my userSlice.js code:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    user: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action ) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
    }
  },
});



export const { login, logout } = userSlice.actions;

export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

and these are the relevant lines of code from app.js

```
import { login, logout, selectUser } from './components/Reducers/userSlice'
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
import { auth } from './firebase';

function App() {
  //allows us to shoot things into the datalayer
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  //selects user from the data layer
  const user = useSelector(selectUser)

  useEffect(() => { //listens for change in user and reloads accordingly
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser){
        //user log in
        dispatch(
          login({
            uid: authUser.uid,
            photo: authUser.photoURL,
            email: authUser.email,
            displayName: authUser.displayName
        }))
      } else {
        //user log out
        dispatch(logout())
      }
    })
  
  }, [dispatch])
  
  return (
    <div className="app">
      {user ? (
        <>
          <Sidebar/>
          <Chat />
        </>
      ) : (
        <Login />
      )}
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is where I call the logout function

```
<div className="sidebar__profile">
        <Avatar onClick={() => auth.signOut()} src={user.photo} />
        <div className="sidebar__profileInfo">
          <h3>{user.displayName}</h3>
          <p>#{user.uid.substring(0, 5)}</p>
        </div>

        <div className="sidebar__profileIcons">
          <MicIcon />
          <SettingsIcon />
          <HeadsetIcon />

        </div>
      </div>
```

this is where I login

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material'
import React from 'react'
import { auth, provider, signInWithPopup } from '../../firebase'
import './Login.css'

function Login() {
    const signIn = () => {
        //google authentication stuff
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error.message)
        })
    }
  return (
    <div className='login'>

        <div className="login__logo">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Discord_white_D.svg/91px-Discord_white_D.svg.png?20180117191712" alt="Disclone logo" />
        </div>

        <Button onClick={signIn}>Sign In</Button>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely subscribing twice to `auth.onAuthStateChange()`. This function returns an unsubscribe function which should be called to clean up (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#returns-firebase.unsubscribe_1). useEffect can take a function as a return value that will be called before it runs again or finishes.

Change your `useEffect()` to capture the unsubcribe function returned and then return it:

```
useEffect(() => { //listens for change in user and reloads accordingly
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser){
        //user log in
        dispatch(
          login({
            uid: authUser.uid,
            photo: authUser.photoURL,
            email: authUser.email,
            displayName: authUser.displayName
        }))
      } else {
        //user log out
        dispatch(logout())
      }
    })
    return unsubscribe
  }, [dispatch])
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help but unfortunately, that doesn't quite fix it. It still gets fired twice sadly

Comment: Even after reloading the page (to clean up previous subscriptions)?

Comment: i did that and it turned out ok! thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! Please mark the answer as accepted so it may help others :)